# How much Active users needed to meet Facebook audience network quality checks?

Tags: facebook

i have 15k downloads and 3.5k active users. but under facebook monetization manager its showing Currently monetizing, but won't be able to continue unless you increase traffic. failing in quality check.[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCBFt.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

I am having the same issue.
Facebook introduced this "Quality Check" only a few weeks ago. The only other person I could find talking about this was here https://www.androidpub.com/2929821 and they switched back to admob :(

I also contacted facebook support.

The latest answer I got was:
Quality Check: One or more of your new platforms have either been taken out of the 60-day quality assessment period or had the assessment period extended. We've introduced a threshold which means platforms don't start getting checked for quality until they reach 70k impressions over a 14-day period.

Comment: I have an app with 5 million downloads and 4.7 rating which was making over $2k per month FAN, after this quality check thing I started getting this same message and doesn't matter what I did, I was always getting this same thing and contacting them is totally useless as it seems that facebook hire the top dumbest people to answer those. My revenue from facebook dropped to $75 per month and today I just removed it from my integration. Thanks to AdMob, my monthly revenue remains the same. So my advice is: just remove facebook from your app. They are the ones needing quality check.

Comment: Facing same issue here as well. No matter what I change I never seem to pass quality check. Followed the facebook ad guidelines exactly to the point but still failing quality check. Also seeing revenue drop to 1/5th from before. Same experience with facebook support. They say they have no info why its failing. They are the one assessed quality check failing then how could they not know why its failing!!!!